# Django - Filtering Related Sets in Templates

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-templates

I have two models;

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    email = models.EmailField()

class WorkOrder(models.Model):
    date_created = models.DateField('Date', default=datetime.now)
    due_date = models.DateField('Due Date')
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Customer')
    STATUS_CHOICES = [
        ('pending', 'Pending'),
        ('approved', 'Approved'),
        ('completed', 'Completed'),
        ('cancelled', 'Cancelled'),
    ]
    status = models.CharField('Status of the work order', max_length=10, choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default='pending')
    description = models.TextField('Description of the work')
```

I wrote a class based list view to make a customer list:

```
class ReportCustomerListView(ListView):

    model = CustomUser
    template_name = 'reports/customer_report.html'

    def get_queryset(self):

        return CustomUser.objects.filter(is_staff=False).filter(is_superuser=False)
```

I would like to prepare a report for the user about its customers so I wanted to show how many pending, approved and completed work orders a customer have. My list template is;

```
<table class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">#</th>
                <th scope="col">First Name</th>
                <th scope="col">Last Name</th>
                <th scope="col">Company</th>
                <th scope="col">Pending Work Orders</th>
                <th scope="col">Active Work Orders</th>
                <th scope="col">Completed Work Orders</th>
                <th scope="col">Draft Bills</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
            <tbody>
                {% for customer in object_list %}
                <tr>
                    <th scope="row">{{ forloop.counter }}</th>
                    <td>{{ customer.first_name }}</td>
                    <td>{{ customer.last_name }}</td>
                    <td>{{ customer.company.company_name }}</td>
                    ...
                    ...
                    ... // the part where I am stuck
```

But I am lost after that after 4 hours of reading I am more confused. I know I can access work orders from

```
>>> Users.objects.get(pk=pk).workorder_set
```

My question is how can I get the customers work orders counts on each status types on the template? In other words how can I filter the related fields on the objects list on template?

Other methods such as filtering on views would also work for me but again I don't know how to do it.

Thank you very much for your time...

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get your related objects then you should try this `django-taggit` install in your app and try this code...
views.py

```
def tagged(request, slug):
tag = get_object_or_404(Tag, slug=slug)
# Filter posts by tag name  
posts = Post.objects.filter(tags=tag)
context = {
    'tag':tag,
    'posts':posts,
}
```

Comment: Is there any other way that does not depend 3rd party apps?